# Salesforce Session ID Invalid right after call

Tags: webservices, session, authorization

I have been through this for a few days now with no luck. I make a session id authorization, that works, and get my session ID like so:

```
$sf_session = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';

        //open connection
        $ch2 = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch2, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $sf_session,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("'X-PrettyPrint' : '1'"),
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'grant_type'=>'password',
                'client_id'=>'XXXXXXXXX',
                'client_secret'=>'XXXXXXXXXX',
                'username'=>'XXXXXXX',
                'password'=>'XXXXXXXXXXX',
            )
        ));

        //execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch2);
            $resultArray = json_decode($result, true);
            $session_id = $resultArray['access_token']; 
            $instance_url = $resultArray['instance_url'];       
            ChromePhp::log($session_id .' - '.$instance_url);

        //close connection
            curl_close($ch2);
```

Great, now I got access and then I make another curl to use a web service. Salesforce docs say to do:
`curl https://instance_name.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/ -H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token'`

So I do:

```
$adobe = $instance_url . '/services/apexrest/echosign_dev1/template/load/a1t31000002HmjV';

        ChromePhp::log($adobe);   
        $ch3 = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($ch3, array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_URL => $adobe,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Bearer $access_token")
            CURLOPT_POST => 1,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'email'=>'XXXXX@gmail.com',
            )
        ));

        //execute post
            $result = curl_exec($ch3);
            ChromePhp::log($result);

        //close connection
            curl_close($ch3);
```

The result: `[{"message":"Session expired or invalid","errorCode":"INVALID_SESSION_ID"}]`

This seems odd since I just got the session ID right before!?!?! I have the connect app set up, my account has API access. Not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing space after Bearer so it will be as shown below

```
    <?php

$sf_session = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';

//open connection
$ch2 = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch2, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $sf_session,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("'X-PrettyPrint' : '1'"),
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'grant_type'=>'password',
                'client_id'=>'XXXX',
                'client_secret'=>'XXXX',
                'username'=>'XXXX',
                'password'=>'XXXX',
        )
));

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch2);
$resultArray = json_decode($result, true);

$session_id = $resultArray['access_token'];
$instance_url = $resultArray['instance_url'];
echo ($session_id .' - '.$instance_url);

//close connection
curl_close($ch2);

$adobe = $instance_url . '/services/data/v26.0/sobjects/';


$ch3 = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch3, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $adobe,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Bearer $session_id"),
        CURLOPT_GET => 1
));

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch3);
var_dump($result);
//close connection
curl_close($ch3);

?>
```

Comment: Ya, I noticed that as well but still no luck like `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token),`

Comment: i have updated with working code. I have added native api call instead of your custom rest api. please test with it first whether it is working for your or not.

Comment: It ended up working with the custom as well. I forgot to change $access_token to $session_id after I updated the header.

Comment: kudos to your effort.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just how you're putting together that header

It should be Header

```
Authorization
```

Value:

```
Bearer Access Token
```

an example of this would be (note the space between Bearer and Session ID)

```
Bearer 00D11000000DFgz!ARwAQHAlFX3...
```

It looks like you are using Header

```
Authorization: Bearer
```

Value

```
Access Token
```

Comment: I have updated the code in my answer but still not working with the new header